# For iterator (loop)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink

I am trying to simulate throw of the ball under angles using simulink.  I'm able to simulate it for one angle but I would like to simulate it using loop. This is what I want to do in simulink using FOR :

`for i=-5:10:85`

Here is picture of my simulink:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you essentially want to rerun your simulation multiple times for different values of the constant Degrees. Instead of using a For Iterator, you may be able to achieve effectively the same result by using vector operations. That is to say, change the value of the constant Degrees from being a scalar value to instead being a vector (in this particular case just set its value to be [5:10:85]).  The outputs of your Simulink model (ie the x and y results) should now be vectors corresponding to the various Degree values.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the blocks into the for-iterator subsystem.  The For Iterator block will output the current iteration, you can use that index (which starts at 0/1) to cycle the angle from -5 to 85 (try to hook the For Iterator block up to a Gain and Sum block).  At each iteration, all the blocks in the for-iterator subsystem will run, and the output of the For Iterator block will increment by one.

The previous solution to make the angles a vector will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Using MATLAB's [for reference page](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/for.html), I'd rewrite your line as:

```
for i=5:10:85
 ...
end
```

Comment: If this question is solved, please tick the answer. If it's incomplete, please enquire with more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Question is not solved, it would work in script ... but I need to have it do by FOR iterator

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question ... What I did is FOR, and it does iterate?

Comment: Well it has to by done in simulik. So it is necessary to use FOR subsystems ... here is its documentation ... I just dont know how to use it ... http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/foriterator.html

Comment: Sorry, I just realised what simulink is. Your question is about making a diagram, not about the code.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote FOR loop how I want my diagram to look ... Can you help me??